# LXC/LXD and AppArmor: Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?

Tags: lxc, apparmor, lxd, zentyal

I am trying to run firewall (Zentyal) on Ubuntu 16.04 inside an LXD container on top of host Arch linux. It requires some AppArmor functionality to do its thing (mainly, DHCP), so I installed AppArmor-enabled kernel on the host and set up the LXD config according to every pointed I found in the internet that related to AppArmor, so it no looks like so:

```
name: router
profiles:
- default
config:
  raw.lxc: lxc.aa_profile= unconfined
  security.nesting: "true"
  security.privileged: "true"
  volatile.base_image:       9c774bed40a5a8a34c2c96c1a93f4d46b0f59cda96defc07bc2c29cf473beb22
      volatile.eth0.name: eth0
      volatile.eth1.name: eth1
      volatile.last_state.idmap: '[]'
      volatile.last_state.power: RUNNING
devices:
  eth0:
    nictype: physical
    parent: enp2s0
    type: nic
  eth1:
    nictype: bridged
    parent: br0
    type: nic
  root:
    path: /
    type: disk
ephemeral: false
```

However, I am still getting those errors in Zentyal logs:

```
    2016/12/22 22:56:48 ERROR> Service.pm:964 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named failed. 
    2016/12/22 22:59:43 ERROR> Sudo.pm:240 EBox::Sudo::_rootError - root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd failed. 
    2016/12/22 22:59:43 ERROR> Service.pm:962 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - Error restarting service: root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd failed. 
    2016/12/22 22:59:43 ERROR> Service.pm:964 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd failed. 
    2016/12/22 22:59:44 ERROR> Sudo.pm:240 EBox::Sudo::_rootError - root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named failed. 
    2016/12/22 22:59:44 ERROR> Service.pm:962 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - Error restarting service: root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named failed. 
    2016/12/22 22:59:44 ERROR> Service.pm:964 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - root command /sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named failed.
```

And when I try to run one of those commands to get more direct error, I get this:

```
/sbin/apparmor_parser --write-cache --replace /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd
/sbin/apparmor_parser: Unable to replace "/usr/sbin/dhcpd".  Permission denied; attempted to load a profile while confined?
```

Is there something more that can be done here, or is it just not doable?

Answer (score 1):

`aa-complain appname` will turn off restrictions but still complain and write to logs.

Install

`sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils`

`sudo aa-logprof` will look through logs and ask you if you want to enable certain permissions for all available profiles.

`sudo aa-cleanprof appname or /pathto/app` will wipe the existing profile

`sudo aa-genprof appname or /pathto/app` will generate a new profile and scan logs for required changes.

`sudo aa-autodep appname or /pathto/app` will attempt to create a profile and all dependancies for an app.

You can set `aa-complain appname` then run through the steps that you want to do with the application. Turn it on, shut it down, restart it, reload it, open files etc. Then run `aa-logprof` to make apparmor look for changes that you can approve or deny.

If that does not work `aa-cleanprof appname` then `aa-autodep appname` would be the quickest way to a new profile. If you get a complaint about an existing profile being present, go to `/etc/apparmor.d/` and `mv` it to  `profilename_OLD`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe it will help someone. However, I moved on to NethServer (CentOS-based) which works well in LXD.